# Would it make sense to have tags deadlands-classic and deadlands-reloaded?

Tags: discussion, status-completed, tags

Deadlands is a scenario / world / plot point that is available for several different game systems, including Savage Worlds, d20, and GURPS.

Recently, there was [a question about how the "history" of the world evolved](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/24855/how-did-the-civil-war-end/27345) from Deadlands "classic" (the original game, with a narrative up to 1878) and Deadlands Reloaded (the *Savage Worlds* version, with a narrative up to 1879).

This has made me think that there may be a need to have more than one tag for Deadlands in the same way that there are more than one tag for DnD-, WoD-, and Cthulhu-related questions. Some questions may apply to one timeline but not to the others, or may apply to one system (e.g. Savage Worlds) but not to the others (GURPS).

On the other hand, I am not familiar with the general policy on that respect and, given that there are only 8 Deadlands-related questions on the site, this may be overkill.

Comment: Why not just have all questions with deadlands be tagged with the appropriate game system they are run on (if mechanics are relevant)?

Comment: I guess that makes sense for the mechanical questions (e.g. deadlands + savage-worlds, deadlands + d20...). But what about the in-game-universe questions (e.g. "How the Civil War end in Deadlands?")?

Comment: @waxeagle The original Deadlands was its own rules system called "Deadlands", which is why this problem exists (it's often distinguished nowadays as "Deadlands Classic")

Comment: It looks like we have tags for all three now... [tag:deadlands] [tag:deadlands-classic] [tag:deadlands-reloaded]

Comment: Sold.  Synonym and merge deadlands -> deadlands-classic.  Lost the tag wiki in the change though and I'm not sure how to get it back, perhaps someone could just reenter something for us.

Comment: @mxyzplk The only issue with synonymizing `deadlands` with `deadlands-classic` is that you are likely to have to retag questions that are intended for Deadlands Reloaded. I'm still in favor of eliminating the `deadlands` tag altogether.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The original Deadlands (generally called "Deadlands Classic") is its own rules system. We are currently using the tag both for rules questions on that system, and for rules questions on mechanics added into "Deadlands Reloaded", the Savage Worlds version, which are unrelated to the Classic ruleset (especially [this question](https://rpg.stackexchange.com/questions/15027/as-a-gm-when-to-force-a-harrowed-player-for-control-of-his-body)). We prevent this problem with other systems, like D&D, by having separate tags for the systems, thus it seems like we should follow precedent and also have separate tags for the systems. Eliminating `deadlands` in favor of `deadlands-classic` would ensure that it is used specifically for rules questions regarding the system.

As for metaplot and settings questions, things fall under one of three categories:

- Common setting elements and backstory for both editions (i.e. stuff happening before 1876)
- Developments during the Classic timeline (1876-1878), which if important enough was included in the metaplot backstory in Reloaded (e.g. "Bloody Sunday")
- Developments during the Reloaded timeline (1879 and onwards)

Given that we currently have only one question on the Deadlands metaplot, a `deadlands-setting` tag seems unnecessary and, unless more such questions are asked, we should be able to use the system tag for the system in which the event was described (or both if described in both). Deadlands d20 and Deadlands GURPS were set in the Classic timeline, but to my knowledge, neither contributed to it, so we should only have two possible tags for metaplot issues, although we could create tags for those systems if rules questions for them come up (although given the fact that both of these versions were not very popular, it's unlikley).

So the short proposal: eliminate `deadlands`, create `deadlands-classic` and `deadlands-reloaded`, which should adequately cover metaplot issues as well. Additional tags (e.g. `deadlands-d20`) could be created if rules questions specifically for those systems should come up (they would not be relevant to metaplot questions).

Comment: Your proposal makes a lot of sense to me. :-)